# Smtp error while send mail with gmail setting

Tags: vb.net, gmail

I am using Gmail setting for sending mail, i got an error like "Failure sending mail." and InnerException as "Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."

My project frame work is .Net 4.8 ,
Programming Language vb ,
OS is Windows 11 .

Anything need to change in Gmail account setting ?

What I have tried:

```
  Imports System.Net
  Imports System.Net.Mail
  Public Class Form1
 
  Public Shared Function ServerCertificateValidationCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal cert As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, ByVal chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    Return True
  End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
      
        Dim Mail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        Dim smtp As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
        Mail.From = New MailAddress("aravind@gmail.com", "Aravind")
        Mail.To.Add("aravind1@gmail.com")
        Mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        Mail.Subject = "Hai Testing Mail"
        smtp = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", "587")
        smtp.EnableSsl = True
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("aravind@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxxxx")
        Dim userstate As Object = Mail
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf ServerCertificateValidationCallback
        smtp.Send(Mail)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString)
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Note i tried with 465 and 25 as ports,still same problem.

1.Port 465 -  error as "Failure sending mail." and InnerException as "Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."

2.Port 25 - error as "Failure sending mail." and InnerException as "Unable to connect to the remote server"

And one more thing i tried with another gmail account with enabled 2 step versification and with app password working fine, i mean from my another account can send mail.

Comment: Why is this tagged with actions-on-google?

Comment: Sorry tag was edited.

Answer (score -1):

try to use port 465 port or 25 port instead of 587,hope this will solve your issue if further details you want then please refer to this link

https://kinsta.com/blog/gmail-smtp-server/

Comment: Thank you for your reply i tried with 465 and 25, still problem, if i use 465 i get same error message which i got above, if i use 25 i got error as "Failure sending mail."and InnerException  as "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: then please follow the link i shared above and try to create an app at google developer to send secure emails , further more you can also refer to sendgrid like other providers for sending emails

Comment: Actually i tried with email password and i tried with  App password which created from Security tab form my account. Because of less secure apps gmail this setting is no longer available . So for both password got same problem.

Comment: Port 25 is almost universally blocked, you cannot use that for Gmail unless you are another SMTP server. But the suggestion to switch to port 465 is not correct either. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: hi, i tried with another gmail account with app password working fine,but why one account working and another cant, both 2 step verification enabled.

Comment: if thats the case then definetly its due to google security settings in profile, there is an option in google settings called allow less secure apps when you make this true then it will allow to send emails without any errors

Comment: allow less secure apps feature from google security already removed, no more feature removed as on from May 2022.